# How do I make maven-eclipse-plugin 2.9 compile classes to the eclipseClasses directory

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I just switched up to maven-eclipse-plugin 2.9 from 2.5.1 and when I do the mvn eclipse:eclipse command, nothing happens inside of the eclipse classes directory.

It is a little disconcerting that the elements in the configuration are not checked, but I can let that slide.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                     <ajdtVersion>1.5</ajdtVersion>
                     <outputDirectory>eclipseClasses</outputDirectory>
                     <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

If I delete the eclipseClasses directory, it get recreated on the mvn build, but it stays empty.

What has changed?  I can't find anything in the maven-eclipse-plugin docs that tells me.

Thanks.
-Kow

Comment: I must note that the 2.9 version of this plugin is much better at rejecting excluded transitive dependencies than earlier versions were.

Comment: also note that I am refreshing the eclipse projects after the build command.